# Terceiro IF ELSE

Tags: javascript, html, css

Então, sou iniciante em javascript e estava praticando fazendo uma função que força as pontuações do campo CPF

```
function maskCpf(){
var c_char = document.getElementById("txtCpf").value.length
   if (c_char == 3){
document.getElementById("txtCpf").value =   document.getElementById("txtCpf").value + "."
                }else if (c_char == 7){
                    document.getElementById("txtCpf").value = document.getElementById("txtCpf").value + "."

            }else if(c_char = 11){
                    document.getElementById("txtCpf").value = document.getElementById("txtCpf").value + "-"

                }
            }
```

So que esse ultimo "else if" não funciona de jeito nenhum. Alguem Help?

Comment: `=` versus `==`

Comment: Esse link pode ser útil: https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/558ea4f5e39efed371000508

Answer (score 3):

Voce esta fazendo uma atribuição ao invés de uma comparação.

```
c_char == 11
```

Se permite uma dica (parece que você é iniciante), voce repete inumeras vezes a expressao

```
document.getElementById("txtCpf").value
```

Pra facilitar sua vida, a legibilidade do código, a futura manutenção e o desempenho pois o javascript percorre apenas uma vez a arvore DOM (Como citou o Paulo Gustavo), use variáveis pra guardar esse valor:

```
var textoCpf = document.getElementById("txtCpf").value;
```

E no futuro, quando uma situação dessa ocorrer, tente usar console.log() com o valor da variável que voce checa pra debugar ;)

Comment: É valido lembrar que essa dica de pegar apenas uma vez o valor de "document.getElementById("txtCpf")" não é somente para melhorar a manutenção, também serve para melhorar desempenho, visto que o código só ira percorrer uma vez a arvore DOM em busca desse elemento

Comment: Bem lembrado @PauloGustavo, vou editar na resposta

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se você percebeu mas no terceiro ELSE IF na condição esta faltando mais um sinal de igual ( = ) .Tente alterar e veja se funcionou.

Answer (score -1):

Na terceira condição você está atribuindo o valor 11 à c_char. O correto é comparar (==).

Outra dica que utilizo bastante é ir colocando "console.log" nas condições, para ver em que hora que o código para, ou onde ele não entra.

por exemplo:

```
else if(c_char = 11){
   console.log(c_char); //retorna valor de c_char
   console.log("Entrou aqui.");
   document.getElementById("txtCpf").value = document.getElementById("txtCpf").value + "-"
}
```